# Why isn't MySQLdb installation working on my 64bit Mac

Tags: python, pydev, mysql-python

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/samwu/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/samwu/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I think the problem must be the 64bit version of python and mysql and the img **_mysql.so** must be 32bit

can anybd give me some suggestions

thx advc!

**---------append1------**

I install MySQLdb just by modify the **mysql_config.path = options['mysql_config']** in **setup_posix.py** and then rebuild like this `python setup.py build` and install,the mysql_config is point to your mysql

**---------append2------**

I can import MySQLdb,but it doesn't work in pydev

I checked the location of MySQLdb module in python shell like this :

```
import MySQLdb
print MySQLdb.__file__
```

**/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/_*init*_.pyc**

then I add the egg to my pydev lib.it works

[CLOSED]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have multiple versions of python installed? It may have installed to your non-default version and therefore won't work with it.

Comment: uh..yep.I have 2.5 and 2.7.and now I fixed it.I will be a real man by installing MySQLdb on 64bit MAC OS X.you know all kinds of torment than 32bit... install the brew then install mysql,uninstall 32bit mysql,reinstall 64bit mysql and update gcc4.2..

Comment: uh..it's not about the python's version.however,thx for your answer,I accpet^_^