# Uninstalling 32-bit MySQL and reinstalling as 64-bit on virtualenv

Tags: python, mysql, django, virtualenv, x86-64

I'm currently setting up a python/django virtualenv on my Mac OS X 10.8.2, which I am trying to use with MySQL. However, when I run "$ python manage.py syncdb" I get an error message that says (clipped):

```
"....
....
....no suitable image found.  Did find:
            /Users/jb/.virtualenvs/MGV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture"
```

After running "$ file $(which mysql)" and "$ file $(which python)", I found that this issue is due to my virtualenv's Python version being x86_64 and its MySQL version being i386 (Also see: http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/discussion/70460/thread/43053990/).  So I'm trying to resolve this by uninstalling the 32-bit MySQL and replacing it with 64-bit. I have found many solutions to uninstalling MySQL on my Mac but can't find any solutions on how to uninstall&reinstall MySQL specifically on a virtualenv. I'm a relatively new programmer so explicit instructions are very much appreciated! :)

Comment: MySQL will not be installed in a specific virtualenv. It is a system-wide application.

Comment: Okay, so I should try uninstalling/reinstalling the MySQL on my MacBook?

Comment: I'm not sure about mac as I have never used them. It could be a problem due to incompatible python-mysqldb package. Try referring [link1](http://www.brambraakman.com/blog/comments/installing_mysql_python_mysqldb_on_snow_leopard_mac_os_x_106/) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060996/why-isnt-mysqldb-installation-working-on-my-64bit-mac). I'm sorry that I couldn't help.

Comment: Check the version and compatibility of `MySQL-python` package.